# Trusting an application (not a user) to post to any user's activity stream

Tags: websphere, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'm trying to use the Social Business Toolkit in Java code on a Connections server to post to users' Connections activity streams.

By default, Connections doesn't allow any user to post to another user's stream, and this restriction applies to my code.

I already know how to configure the WidgetContainer application in WAS to trust individual users to post to other users' streams, but that requires either that all users are trusted or our code is somehow made to run as a special trusted user. The former is undesirable due to the potential for spam, and the latter is undesirable because we have to configure login details for the special user in the application.

Instead of trusting users, is there any way (either through the SBT or with WAS/Connections features) to make Connections trust our *application* to post to users' streams, even when it authenticates as a user who is not otherwise trusted to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Generally, you need an Application Specific User as you noted in your WidgetContainer reference.  What I do is create a new Connections User, MyApplication, I grant that user the trustedThirdParty Applicaiton role.

Today, this method is the only one promoted.